# Не могу подключить <curl/curl.h> к своему Clion проекту на Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, clion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int getCurrentMMR(std::string steamId) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        std::string url = "https://api.opendota.com/api/players/" + steamId + "/mmr";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    json j = json::parse(readBuffer); 

    return j["solo_competitive_rank"];
}
```

перепробовал много способов, не получается
fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Ddd)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Ddd ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(C:/Program Files/11)
add_executable(Ddd main.cpp)
```

Comment: Покажи как ты загружаешь эту библиотеку в CMake.

Comment: find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(<Ddd> ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/lib)

Comment: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Comment: Прикрепи всё содержимое **CMakeLists.txt** к вопросу, с форматированием и подсветкой, будь человеком.

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Ddd)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Ddd ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY C:/Users/msham/CLionProjects/Dota/CURL/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(C:/Program Files/11)
add_executable(Ddd main.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Ddd)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR D:/curl-8.0.1_8-win64-mingw/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY D:/curl-8.0.1_8-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Ddd main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Ddd PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Открой **PowerShell**, и туда вбей следующее:

```powershell
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg install curl
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

После чего тебе выдаст что-то вроде этого:

```
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.
CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/ellen/git/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries. Linking will be handled automatically. Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.
```

Вот эту строчку (только путь будет другой) `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/ellen/git/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` вбиваешь сюда:

[image: CLion vcpkg integration]

Вот это запиши в **CMakeLists.txt**:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Ddd)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Ddd main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Ddd PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

Comment: я скачал архив с этого сайта https://curl.se/windows/ и кидал путь к нему, это же он да? (не получился твой вариант)

Comment: @GihubEnjoyer что пишет?

Comment: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Comment: @GihubEnjoyer какая у тебя ОС и какая IDE?

Comment: Windows 10 Clion

Comment: @GihubEnjoyer обновил ответ, так точно будет работать.

Comment: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CURL" with any of
  the following names:

    CURLConfig.cmake
    curl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CURL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CURL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CURL"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Comment: @GihubEnjoyer это на каком моменте? Ты все пункты сделал из ответа моего?

Comment: Сделал все по инструкции релоуднул смейк выдало это

Comment: Попробуй так, я поменял там CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Comment: ты вот это добавил в CMake options? `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/ellen/git/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`
путь поменял на тот что для тебя актуален?

Comment: я вбил тот который мне выдал PowerShell

Comment: -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/msham/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake